# Highlight Questions You Asked

Tags: feature-request, highlighting

While I realise if you want to see your own question, you only have to go to your user page and look there, I think it would be handy to have some kind of highlighting of questions you asked on the question lists.

Comment: I love it! -3 and no comments or anything! Fantastic discussion there meta team. *Shakes head*

Comment: The suggestion just seems silly. You can't remember the questions you asked?.... and how often do your questions show up on the questions page anyway? ------- Now, dimming questions you've already read.... that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

Why? It distracts from answering the OPs questions. Example scenario:

*Oooh I have a question.*

*Hey while I'm here I might as well answer some other questions.(Scroll down the list of newest questions)*

*Ooohh hey shinny thing (clicks on it)*

*Dooohh*

Also, you get notifications. And does it really hurt to periodically check?

In addition if you have a question and it has one of your favorite tags you will see it highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better idea, is to add a feature to mark certain users as interesting or ignored, highlighting their questions just like the tags.

Then you could add yourself to the list.